# Xcode 8 automatically managing signing produces "conflicting provisioning settings" error

Tags: xcode, provisioning

How do I assign correct provisioning profile to run Xcode app via Xcode -> Product -> Profile ?

With earlier version of Xcode, a provisioning profile was generated automatically by Xcode and I just selected that option to make a profile build. The generated profile had * at the end. However, with new Xcode, this is no longer generated.

Tried to click on "Automatically Manage Signing" but did not work for me it says "app-X has conflicting provisioning settings." Cannot attempt to build via Profile to install on device directly from Xcode.

How that's done with Xcode 8.3.2?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/pGGz9 you need to set the profiles in here

Comment: Also if you want to use automatically manage signing for running your app on device you need to select the team by adding your apple account in Xcode and check this as well :http://imgur.com/a/A1Cco

Answer (score 1):

Go to build setting and select your profile, if you are using provisioning then it will be shown like "iPhone Distribution: account name(HFGTY453HH)" like that. Set that profile for every option there.

[image]

select your profile and developer team and it will then manage it self... and you done it..

Note: check if your certificate has already installed in your system, else, download it again and by double clicking install it again.

Thanks